# wget.exe for windows 10

Tags: windows, wget

I'm attempting to download wget because a provisioner I am using can't retrieve certain information without it (naturally this issue doesn't come up at work but at work, I have a Mac, at home, I have a 64bit windows 10 machine). I have tried the wget.exe files from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/ and [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/)  but no luck. Are there any current issues with wget on Windows 10, if not does anyone have any ideas what my issues may be?

Comment: Try cURL  http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: I use the one from https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki but I use Windows 7

Comment: You should expand on 'no luck'. I used a mac once but... no luck

Comment: Anyone with success rate of installing still on windows 10 ???

Comment: I used this [excellent instructions](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/install-and-use-wget-in-windows-10/) and installed the [exe installer from Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/wget/1.11.4-1/wget-1.11.4-1-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=excellmedia). Then you need to set the path according to the instruction (1st link in this comment).

Comment: I've used wget from `scoop`, `msys2` and they work fine on windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

eternallybored build will crash when you are downloading a large file.
This can be avoided by disabling LFH (Low Fragmentation Heap) by GlobalFlag registry.

Comment: Is an alternative build available? Requiring users to download Deubgging Tools for Windows to set a global flag and work around a bug in the executable seems a bit much.

Comment: After I updated Windows 10 to the latest version, wget.exe 1.19.4 (x64) on exterenallybored.org works well. But it can not work on old Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

[GNU Wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) is a free network utility to retrieve files from the World Wide Web using HTTP and FTP, the two most widely used Internet protocols.

It works great for me on win 10

[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/bcj8w0)

Comment: Thing is, that's WGet 1.11.  The current version is more like WGet 1.18. The binary download doesn't include complete dependencies; it needs at least four DLLs that aren't included in the download.

Comment: This works for me cleanly. I installed using the Windows installer.

Answer (score 1):

I use it on Windows 10 without issue. Don't know which version it is.  The digital signature in the properties says March 19, 2015.  I have it in a folder on the c drive called `ab` and I use:

> c:\ab\wget --no-check-certificate https://myURL -O c:\ab\Save_Name.txt

and it saves the file as `Save_Name.txt`